# Another way to write: if some_variable && some_valiable.size == 2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In Ruby & in RoR I oft find myself testing whether an object exists, then whether an object's properties match some criteria. Like so:

```
if params[:id] && params[:id].size == 40
  ...do stuff
end
```

Is there a more efficient way to do this? Something like:

```
if params[:id].size == 40 rescue false
```

but without using the rescue?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

With Rails 2.3 you can use Object#try method:

```
if params[:id].try(:size) == 40
  # do stuff
end
```

try will return nil when called on nil (with any arguments). Hope that makes sense.

Comment: @neutrino Awesome! Didn't know about that at all, great answer. I would +1, but I reached my limit :(

Comment: `try` is part of `ActiveSupport`. You can use this outside of Rails.

Answer (score 0):

Try the andand gem:

```
require 'andand'

if params.andand.size == 40
  ...do stuff
end
```

Comment: Hmm.  They're a bit different, though similar.
-r

Answer (score 0):

You can do it witout additional gems.

```
if params[:id].to_a.size == 40
    ... do stuff
end
```